# Unreliable fetch request with nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

This is my post route

```
router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
    // console.log(req.user);
    let ts = Date.now();
    let date_ob = new Date(ts);
    let date = date_ob.getDate();
    let month = date_ob.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
    let time = date_ob.getUTCHours() + "-"+date_ob.getUTCMinutes()+"-"+date_ob.getUTCMilliseconds()
    let createDate =  year + "-" + month + "-" + date+"T"+time;
    // console.log(req.body.image);

    let data = await Example.create({
            authorName:req.user.username, 
            createDate: createDate, 
            description:req.body.desc,
            title:req.body.title,
            tags:req.body.tag,
            examples: req.body.code,
            image: req.body.image
    }).then(function(data){
    res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(function(err){
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

On clicking the save example button the client sends a fetch request to save the example to my db

```
async function saveExample(data) {

  // call snapshot function
  let snapshot = getCanvasSnapshot();
  console.log(snapshot);


  const url = "/examples";
  var tag = "";
  if (document.getElementById("easy").checked) {
    tag = "easy";
  } else if (document.getElementById("medium").checked) {
    tag = "medium";
  } else {
    tag = "tough";
  }
  let jsonData = {
    code: data,
    desc: document.querySelector("#desc1").value,
    title: document.querySelector("#title1").value,
    tag: tag,
    image: snapshot,
  };
  // console.log("Json Data: ", jsonData);

  //
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonData), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("ouput");
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The snapshot contains a screenshot of a canvas in a url encoded base64 format with the meta tags.

The first time I try to save an example it does so without any errors, but the second time I try doing it, it throws this error.

```
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796496+00:00 app[web.1]: BadRequestError: request aborted
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796497+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:238:10)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796498+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:390:28)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796498+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:179:10)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796498+00:00 app[web.1]: at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:102:25)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796499+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:64:5)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796499+00:00 app[web.1]: at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:596:9)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796499+00:00 app[web.1]: at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:590:3)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796499+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
2022-05-12T19:11:02.796500+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

Some more info about how my server is configured

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb',extended:false}));
```

I am at loss as to what might be causing this that it saves an example to my dv sometimes and other times it doesn't.

Comment: Could you provide more upper code, and specs about what libraries you are using?

Answer (score -1):

1st
this is not required.

```
    let ts = Date.now();
    let date_ob = new Date(ts);
```

just use:

```
let date_ob = new Date();
```

Also you mix async/await with .then/.catch all the time;
Additionally you do not have .then for fetching data (only .catch);

And most important - fetch is for url `/example` and your path is defined only for `/`.

Without some more code or more testing from our side, i cannot help you more

Comment: Nothing of this is a problem. This could be a comment, but not an answer.